# C# DataTable, copy number to excel in string format because first digit is 0?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datatable, leading-zero

I need to be able to copy a DataTable in C# to excel, and I have one small problem. When I import a number, lets say, '0203', it comes into Excel as '203'. Our software is very particular and it needs the zero. I am aware adding an apostrophe(') before the number will allow the proper format, but if I manually add it into C#, it doesn't work when copying over. You have to click in and out of each cell, then the single quote method works. But clicking each cell defeats the entire purpose.

Is there a way to copy over a number like '0203' into excel with the formatting?

It needs this way in excel because we have a program that allows data entry through excel. it gives an error when importing into our software.

I added an apostrophe in C#. It doesn't format the cell until you click in. Example: '0203 instead of 0203 showing in excel, giving an error for my import.

Comment: Set the cell (column / the whole workbook) format as Text.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/questions/710857/how-to-show-leading-zero-in-excel-through-csharp